# Calculation of derivative projection of differential Radon matrix

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to write a matlab code  for finding the differential Radon Matrix.
[image: Radon Transform].

[image]

[image: The formula for differential Radon Matrix is]

Above are formula  for Radon Transform and differential Radon Matrix  .
What I get is the formula for Radon Matrix

`R = radon(I)
R = radon(I,theta)
[R,xp] = radon(___)`

But I unable to figure out how to use this code for calculating differential Radon Matrix

Comment: You already have the formula, why don't you directly code it in Matlab

Comment: In matlab R=radon(I,theta) it does not involve variation in K which I need

Comment: @Dsp guy sam 2)Also if I directly  use formula theta is varying from  -10 to 10 at 0.1 degree so we get a particular ratio of xm and ym and since this ratio is changing we get different Ntheta so matrix it will lead to row vector of different size . Is this apporoach correct of getting different size row vector instead of getting a uniform 2D matrix